# What is the best way to handle autocomplete="off"? is it JavaScript or code behind(VB.Net)

Tags: javascript, jquery, vb.net

I read couple of articles on this and I am aware of how `autocomplete="off"` works. Now I have to use this in our application`(internet and intranet application)` and there are couple of articles, blogs gives their own perspective, I would like to know what experts suggest to use in an actual world.

At present I have couple of options:

1. Mark `autocomplete="off"` in default(login) page within`form` tag.
2. Write a jQuery function in the Master Page

   `$(document).ready(function () { $("input").attr("autocomplete", "off"); });`
3. Implement same in Code behind(C#)

   ```
        Public abstract class BasePage : Page
         {
           protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
            {
              //Handling autocomplete issue generically
              if (this.Form != null)
                {
                   this.Form.Attributes.Add("autocomplete", "off");
                }

               base.OnLoad(e);
             }
          }
   ```

I would like to know which is the best way to handle this scenario. What I am actually thinking is is there any way we can implement this in `web.config` level.

Comment: You can set in form tag as well as `$(document).ready(function () { $("form").attr("autocomplete", "off"); });`

Comment: @jishansiddique, as I mentioned above my query is not like how to implement, my query was about which one is the best option to use in real world entity.

Comment: You can use any of those, there's no better or worse option. None of them really is working in the real world, where a hacker opens the DevTools, and rewrites the attribute in the HTML.